# PHP MySQLi UPDATE statement compared to MySQL function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The information that I've come across when it relates to **MySQLi UPDATEs** seems to differ from the old **MySQL** function in PHP.

Using the **MySQL** function I used to write:

```
UPDATE table SET (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
WHERE col1 = '4'
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but in **MySQLi** it seems that one directly maps a **column** with its value, like:

```
UPDATE table SET col1='val1', col2='val2', col3='val3', col4='val4' WHERE col1 = '4'
```

Am I out bicycling in my reasoning and discovery?

Comment: I think you are mixing `UPDATE` and `INSERT` syntax.

Comment: MYSQL is MYSQL. Doesn't matter whether you're using the MYSQL, PDO or MYSQLi functions the actual syntax will always be the same. They just handle differently.

Comment: You **did not** used to write this with mysql. that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for UPDATE query

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Syntax for an INSERT query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

In your first example you write an UPDATE query but use VALUES in addition to using SET. VALUES in this statement is not used.

```
UPDATE table SET (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
WHERE col1 = '4'
```

Your second example is accurate syntax for both mysql and mysqli.

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1='val1', col2='val2', col3='val3', col4='val4' 
WHERE col1 = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html), the first example is wrong, that's the INSERT syntax. The second example is the syntax for UPDATE, it doesn't matter if you use `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*` or PDO, the syntax is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas, both mysql and mysqli have same syntax/rule for insert/update as well. I feel you are mixing update and insert query.

The only difference between mysql and mysqli update is the work (i). The update query which is working in mysql will also work with mysqli.